# Change height without effect on other elemetns

Tags: css, height, html-lists

How do you change the height of an `li` element when it is hovered over without effecting other `li` elements, like position, but I'd like the hovered `li` to overlap with others below, like it has the greatest z-index.

In this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ktxessch), I want to height to change but not move any elements below the hovered `li` element.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ktxessch/

Comment: It looks like the jsfiddle you posted does change what you need.  What else are you needing to do beyond this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the margin to compensate for the height change.

```css
ul.products li {
  width: calc(25% - 12.5px);
 display: inline-block;
  transition: box-shadow .15s ease;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
 margin:0 10px 10px 0;
 text-align: center;
  height:50px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
ul.products li:hover {
  height:70px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="products">
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
</ul>
```

In a normal setting, you have 50px as the height and 10px as the bottom margin.  In the above example, I've added the extra 20px to the original `margin-bottom` (for a total of 30px) and just set the hover `margin-bottom` to 10px and the height to 70px.

That way, the total height will always be 80 pixels with the margin and you can shift the `li` height without an issue.

**Edit:** [@Mr Lister's method](http://jsfiddle.net/sy5hd7t8/1/) actually is much closer to your original intention as it makes the hovered `li` overlap the other `li` items below. I had misunderstood what you meant in your original unedited question by 'greater z-index' when I edited it.  My apologies.

Comment: Or, you can make the items overlap, since you can make margins negative as well. [Re-updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sy5hd7t8/1/).

Comment: Your solution is actually closer to what he wanted as I had misunderstood the last part of his original question.  Overlapping is what he originally had in mind.  I updated my answer to reflect this and I've also pushed an update to the question to clarify that.

Comment: Yes. Also note that in my example, there is no need to set the z-index, since relative positioning is enough to put the element above all other elements. (Of course if there are other positioned elements with a z-index on the page, you will need an explicit z-index on the hovered ones that is higher than the non-hovered ones.)